# Getting 3 best Posts per Month with three different queries

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the `row_number` function.

This is my SCHEMA :

[image]

I am trying to build a query that would output the top value for Post_impressions within a date range (I.E. a month) WHEN the RowNumber is set to 1, the second best value when it is set to 2 and so on.

Here is the query I came up with so far

```
SELECT Post_timestamp, 
    Post_impressions, 
    Post_tipo, 
from 
    (SELECT Post_timestamp, 
    Post_impressions, 
    Post_tipo,
    FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(Post_timestamp), DAY)) as TheDate,
      row_number() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(Post_timestamp), DAY)) ORDER BY Post_impressions DESC) AS RowNumber
  from `***DATABASENAME***`
WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND TheDate BETWEEN "2021-07-01" AND "2021-07-31";
```

Thans for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 31 rows because you're partitioning the subquery by day, and each partition has a RowNumber = 1.  You could partition your query by month <strike>but I suspect that wouldn't address all your use cases, particularly when you want to look at a time period over multiple partitions.</strike>

<strike>Alternatively</strike> if your use case is limited to month over month, you can simply partition by the month.

```
SELECT Post_timestamp, 
        Post_impressions, 
        Post_tipo, 
    from 
        (SELECT Post_timestamp, 
        Post_impressions, 
        Post_tipo,
        FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(Post_timestamp), day)) as TheDate,
          row_number() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(Post_timestamp), month)) ORDER BY Post_impressions DESC) AS RowNumber
      from `***DATABASENAME***`
    WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND TheDate BETWEEN "2021-07-01" AND "2021-07-31";
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn t work. The top Post per impressions isn`t the result when RowNumber is 1, neither is it the second best when RowNumber is 2.

Comment: Can you explain why not?  I tested this and produced the results OP was looking for @GuillaumeAT